# How to access a table using the caption's <a> tag in xpath/selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to access an html table (via selenium/python) with the following section:

```html
<table class="results table">
  <caption>
    <a name="Student">Students (x)</a>
    " 
 
  A student ID is required to view student details.
    
    "
    </caption>
  <thread>...</thread>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">
        <a href="people.cfm?id=THIS_ID">THIS PERSONS NAME</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

where x is the number of students found, and THIS PERSON'S NAME is a clickable link to a result of the search

The page is a database of people in my school, and when you search a name each type of person (student, faculty, alumni, etc) is placed on its own table. I am just trying to access the student table, but I can't seem to figure out the xcode to reach it.

I know that I need something like

```
"//table[caption= ??]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"
```

but I don't know what to put in the brackets. I tried to do this:

```
"//table[caption= a[@name='Student']]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"
```

but I don't think I can access a tag (`<a>`) from within the bracket search criteria of another(`<table>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're trying to do.

```
//table[caption/a[@name='Student']]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a
```

Comment: While this is a valid XPath, it will return a text node and not a WebElement so it's not a valid locator.  To make it a valid locator remove the `text()` part at the end of it.

Comment: Rather than using an index like `..\td[1]\..`, instead find the right TD using the class="name" like `//table[caption/a[@name='Student']]/tbody/tr/td[@class='name']/a` so if the `A` tag moves `TD`s, the locator will be less likely to break.